# groovy take how to reimplement

Tags: groovy, take

The take and drop methods were added to the list object in groovy v 1.8.1, and work like this:

```
def list = ['Simple', 'list', 'with', 5, 'items']   
assert list.take(2) == ['Simple', 'list']
```

I only have v 1.8.0 available to me.  How can I reimplement my own version of list.take(2) using Groovy v1.8.0 ?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
def list = ['Simple', 'list', 'with', 5, 'items']  
def limit = 2 
assert list['0..'+limit] == ['Simple', 'list']
```

When I try this I get an exception.

Comment: Should be noted that `take` also exists for Iterators and Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing might accomplish the same goal:

```
def list = ['Simple', 'list', 'with', 5, 'items']   
assert list[0..1] == ['Simple', 'list']
```

Comment: This might work. Would it be possible to make something like this work? 'assert list['0..'+2]'  with intention of changing the 2 number to an argument that is passed in.  Groovy throws missingPropertyException when I try this.

Comment: just do `list[0..limit]` however, you should check the length of the list to ensure limit isn't too large. which is why `take` was added to groovy

Answer (score 1):

you could do it the way groovy does it

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L6498

```
public static <T> List<T> take(List<T> self, int num) {
    if (self.isEmpty() || num <= 0) {
        return createSimilarList(self, 0);
    }
    if (self.size() <= num) {
        List<T> ret = createSimilarList(self, self.size());
        ret.addAll(self);
        return ret;
    }
    List<T> ret = createSimilarList(self, num);
    ret.addAll(self.subList(0, num));
    return ret;
}
```

the method `createSimilarList` can be found here

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.java#L162

Comment: Thanks - my bad... I was thinking it would be nice to reimplement it in the groovy 1.8.0 language itself rather than in java - is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as GargantuChet's answer, you can slice it, but using an exclusive range:

```
List.metaClass.take { n ->
    def len = [n,delegate.size()].min()
    delegate[0..<len]
}

assert [1,2,3,4].take(2) == [1,2]
assert [1,2].take(2) == [1,2]
assert [1].take(2) == [1]
assert [].take(2) == []
```

Comment: I later saw GargantuChet's update and that works too if I just change ['0..'+limit] -> [0..limit] which is probably the most elegant.  Sorry GargantuChet I checked this answer before noticing your later update.

Comment: @cspeter8 imho, this is the better answer as it handles lists that are smaller than `limit`.  Using pure slicing without this check could lead to an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` (indeed, this is why `take` was created, as it can be a pain to say _"Get me up to 4 characters from the String"_, you end up writing lots of bounds checking code)